# Pytest not showing failure summary if assert is called after a certain line

Tags: python, logging, pytest, assert

For some reason, the failure/error summary does not appear if my assert is called after a certain line of code.

Working code:

```
def test_me():
    assert 1 == 2
```

Example of failure summary showing properly:

```
...
==================== FAILURES ======================
>       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

fail.py:12: AssertionError
============== short test summary info =============
FAILED fail.py::test_me - assert 1 == 2
...
```

If I add a line in between:

```
def test_me():
    do_something() # this is a huge custom library that someone else wrote
    assert 1 == 2
```

The failure summary no longer appears:

```
...
============== short test summary info =============
FAILED fail.py::test_me - assert 1 == 2
...
```

I have tried setting flags like tb, -rA but none of them seemed to be related to the issue.
Without looking into the huge library, does anyone have any idea what might be causing the failure summary to disappear and how to make it appear? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through that library to check where its failing, it looks like control never reaching to assert statement

Comment: Thanks, I have not tried debugging through the library but I can give it a try. Wait if control is never reaching to assert statement, why would the failure appear in short test summary but not generate a failure summary?

Comment: try using --tb=short or --tb=long